# GTM implementation in magento 2

Tags: magento2, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement GTM in magento 2 product and checkout. But i could not able to make it successful. Please help me to implement gtm on magento 2.

Comment: This is too broad. Since GTM requires a dataLayer to track ecommerce properly this is not a trivial task in Magento, and it would be much quicker and easier if you used a ready-made extension. Maybe you find an answer on the Magento stackexchange site: https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=google+tag+manager

Comment: we have purchased the extension for gtm implementation. Still its not working because we have done lot of customization. Due to customization its not working.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 is providing default GTM functionality in inetegrate it.

To Inetgrate GTM please follow below steps:

Go To: Admin Panel => Stores => Configuration => Sales => Google API

In Google Analytics:

Enable you module and Select Account Type : Google Tag Manager 
Add you GTM Container ID over there just click on Save Config, GTM will start working.

Please refere blog 
[GTM Magento 2 Doc](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/google-tag-manager.html)